# Array Filter and Array Values taking a long time on large PHP array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of code running a simulation.

```
public function cleanUpHouses(\DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Collection $collection)
{
    $houses = $collection->getHouses();

    $housesLength = count($houses);
    $filterValues = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $housesLength; $i++) {
        if(!$this->houseModel->hasBeenAttacked($houses[$i])) {
            break;
        }

        $houses[$i]->setCurrentAttackers(0);

        if($this->houseModel->requiresDestroying($houses[$i])) {
            $houses[$i] = null;
            $filterValues = true;
        }
    }
    if($filterValues) {
        $houses = array_values(array_filter($houses));
    }

    $collection->setHouses($houses);

    return $collection;
}
```

However, `$collection` contains an array (`$getHouses`) of up to and over 1 million results, although it will never need to iterate over all of these results, the line `$houses = array_values(array_filter($houses))` is taking ages due to the sheer size of the array, (up to 3 seconds each time this line is ran).

I have to keep the array index numeric, and there can be no null values in this array.

I was hoping `unset($array[$i])` would shift the array elements after the element being unset 'down' in key, so if I was to `unset($array[5])`, then `$array[6]` would become `$array[5]`, however it doesn't seem to work like this.

The `break` conditional is there because, on an iteration if the house under iteration hasn't been attacked, then it's safe to assume any other house after that in the array has also not been attacked.

Is there an optimal, less resource heavy way to achieve this?

I can't *really* restructure this at the moment as it's in unit tests and I need it finishing ASAP, the approach isn't great, but eh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most painless way to achieve this is something like this:

While you are looping through the array of houses, and you need to unset something in the array, you can cheat the loop itself.

```
if($this->houseModel->requiresDestroying($houses[$i])) {
    // $houses[$i] = null;
    // when you unset the $i house in the array,
    // you can simply switch it with the last one in the array, keeping in mind,
    // that this may break your logic with the break condition, so will want to change that as well.
    $lastHouse = $houses[$housesLength - 1];
    $houses[$i] = $lastHouse;
    unset($houses[$housesLength - 1]);
    $i--;
    $housesLength--; // by doing the top two lines we would make the loop check the last house again.
    $shouldBreak = false; // this will keep your logic with the break if later.
    // $filterValues = true; // you can remove this line here.
}
```

You would want to set up a variable for the break condition before the for loop starts.

```
$shouldBreak = true;
for($i = 0; $i < $housesLength; $i++) {
    ...
```

And now for the condition itself

```
if(!$this->houseModel->hasBeenAttacked($houses[$i]) && true === $shouldBreak) {
    break;
} else {
    $shouldBreak = true; // we set $shouldBreak = false when we unset the last house,
    // so we would want to keep checking the houses not to break the logic.
}
```

We only will remove the last element in the array, so it will be kept numeric.